# iOs 9 WhatsApp share from within iframe in safari isn't working

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, safari

I have a web app supplied through iframe for other websites to embed.

In it, there's a share button for Whatsapp and it doesn't seem to work (the button isn't responding) in safari in devices with iOs 9+.

When testing the application in a non-iframe environment, the share button seems to work.

The code for the share link:

```
  <div class="whatsapp sharer">
    <a ng-href="{{'whatsapp://send?text=' + message}}" target="_blank" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"></a>
  </div>
```

It seems to be a problem because of the security changes made in iOs9, but is there any way to bypass this?